# How do I make 3D graph of a 3x100 or a 4x100 database

Tags: plotting

I can import the database into Mathematica using the command Import["filename"], but I do not know how to plot or graph the 3x100 database (x, y, f(x,y)) into a graph of points.  The same applies to a database 4x100 (x,y,z,f(x,y,z)),

Comment: Have you looked at ListPLot3D?

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica has a very extensive 3D visualization library; I would start by looking at these pages:

- [ListPointPlot3D](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPointPlot3D.html)
- [ListPlot3D](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot3D.html)
- [ListContourPlot3D](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListContourPlot3D.html)
- [Plotting Lists of Data](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PlottingListsOfData.html)

Those are the functions that are most likely to help you based on what you've said about your data, but I've found that sometimes you just need to write the graphics objects yourself; when/if you get to that point, I'd recommend these pages:

- [The Structure of Graphics](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TheStructureOfGraphics.html)
- [Graphics Options and Styling](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/GraphicsOptionsAndStyling.html)
- [Symbolic Graphics Language](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SymbolicGraphicsLanguage.html)
- [Graphics3D](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics3D.html)

Comment: All the ListPlot commands, as far as I can tell, determine the function from within Mathematica.  In my case, I generate the coordinates and the function outside of Mathematica and need to populate a database in Mathematica.  When I tried the command 'Import["file"], as I did before, I cannot import the "file" name that I used before, but instead get an error message that gives a number of options, one of which is "{import, verb, transfer}" which it explains that this command would "transfer (electronic data) into a database or document".  This is just what I want to do.

Comment: It's very unclear from your comment and your question what you are having trouble with. Are you unable to import the data or unable to plot it? If you can't import the data you'll need to tell us what file format they are in and what error message you received. Ideally, upload the file to somewhere like file dropper so that we can reproduce the error. Right now, your question looks like it's only about plotting, but this comment makes it sound like you had an error when importing.

Comment: I have solved my import problem, but I have two long files with 3 or 4 columns - (x,y,f(x,y)) or (x,y,z,f(x,y,z)),  I don't know how to use ListPlot or ListPlot3D or any other command to plot these files.

Comment: Your question and comments right now are so vague that I can't understand what you've done so far or what is going wrong. If you have read the help pages linked in this answer, please let us know what you've tried and how it has failed. Right now I can't tell if you don't know how to use ListPointPlot3D because there is something strange about your data or if you don't know how to use it because you haven't tried.